Prove that $ \cup_{i \ge 1} X_i ^{-1} (\mathcal{B})$ is a $\pi$-system for $(X_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ iid random variables
I want to show that $ \cup_{i\ge 1} X_i ^{-1} (\mathcal{B})$ is a $\pi$-system for $(X_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ iid random variables. Where $ \mathcal{B}$ is the Borel sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}$.
If I take sets $ X_i ^{-1} (B_1) \cap X_i ^{-1} (B_2)$, then this follows straightforward. However, I am unsure how to show that $X_i ^{-1} (B_1) \cap X_j ^{-1} (B_2)$ is in $ \cup_{i\ge 1} X_i ^{-1} (\mathcal{B})$ for $ i \neq j$.
Any tips would be great. Also I am not sure if this statement is even correct.

Just not true. You cannot prove this. (BTW, i.i.d. has nothing to do with this ).

@geetha290krm Thank you!
